# multiprocessing - not completing all jobs

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python3.8

```
def multiprocessDailyData(filename):
    st = time.time()
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
        -------more codes here -----
    except Exception as e:
        trace_back = sys.exc_info()[2]
        line = trace_back.tb_lineno
        print("Failed {}".format(line), e)
        print(filename)
        os.unlink(filename)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2)
    start = time.time()
    for file in filename:
            p.apply_async(multiprocessDailyData, [file])
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Complete")
    end = time.time()
    print('total time (s)= ' + str(end-start))
```

The above code iterates through a bunch of files from a folder.  I have 300 files in all.  The machine has 8 threads and we are using 6 of them.

The problem I am facing is inconsistent.  The processing of all the files gets completed on certain days and on other days, the last file remains to be picked up.  This behavior of processing 299 files and keeping 1 pending is consistent in the sense it is always the last file that remains from being picked up for processing.

When I did `htop`, on every occasion I could see the program being alive on six cores though there is no processor activity.    The python program is being called from inside a bash script.  The bash script has further subsequent processing parts.

When I pkill the python process manually, the other processes gets kicked off.  Since this is random, I could not figure out why this is happening nor I could see any error messages from try catch as the process is still trying everytime.

There is no problem in the inputfile, coz when I process it manually, it gets completed without an error.

Comment: Can you see if the 'stuck' file actually gets started by a subprocess, and then gets stuck somewhere when processing it?

Comment: @TomDalton Thank you, I can check that today if it gets stuck again